# Can relativization change the direction of separation?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, relativization

Are any $A$, $B$, and $O$ such that:

- $O$ is a set (for oracle),
- $A$ and $B$ are the names of two known complexity classes,
- $A^X$ and $B^X$ have well-defined accepted meanings,
- $A=A^\emptyset\subset B^\emptyset=B$, i.e. $A$ is strictly contained in $B$,
- $A^O\supset B^O$, i.e. $A^O$ strictly contains $B^O$.

In the case of $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{EXP}$, it's impossible to find an oracle $O$ relative to which $\mathsf{P}^O$ strictly contains $\mathsf{EXP}^O$ since a $\mathsf{EXP}^X$ can completely simulate every step of any turing machine in $\mathsf{P}^X$ (i.e. the time hierarchy theorem relativizes).

I'm wondering if there are complexity classes $A$, $B$ s.t. $A \subset B$, yet for some oracle $O$, $A^O \supset B^O$. In other words, can the direction of strict inclusion change when complexity classes are relativized?

Comment: Since you wrote “in the most general case,” what is your definition of “complexity class”?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: good point. Anything in the complexity zoo is fair game.

Comment: About the section labelled as “Related”: (1) It is better to avoid using L because L is the name of a well-known complexity class.  I suggest HALT as your language represents the halting problem.  (2) Why is P^HALT = EXP^HALT?  I think that P^HALT ≠ EXP^HALT by the time-hierarchy theorem.  Are there any subtleties in defining EXP^O?

Comment: Also note that there are more than one definition for space-bounded complexity classes in a relativized world, depending on whether you count the oracle tape as part of space or not.  “Take a complexity class, and attach an oracle” is not a nice operation because we are usually using different oracle models e.g. when we talk about L^O (where the oracle tape usually does not count towards the space complexity) and when we talk about PSPACE^O (where the oracle tape usually counts towards the space complexity).  I think that there was a recent question related to this point….

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Changed the oracle from $L$ to $Accept$. Can you expand on why $P^{Halt}$ strictly contains $EXP^{Halt}$?

Comment: It is the other way around.  P^HALT ⊊ EXP^HALT, and as I said, it is just the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: Not all classes on the complexity zoo admit oracles: what would $CFL^O$ mean?

Comment: The zoo used to display a warning sign reading “Please do not feed oracles to the complexity classes! These classes require a specially balanced diet to ensure proper relativization.” Unfortunately, it seems to be gone (or well hidden) in its Wiki reincarnation.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Yes, but we're looking for inclusion the other way. I.e. some oracle relative to which $Big^O$ is strictly contained in $Small^O$ ....

Comment: In case it is not clear, the point of my comment is that your claim that P^Accept = EXP^Accept is incorrect.

Comment: @tkxue, the same argument that you use to say that the direction cannot change for P and EXP shows that they cannot be equal either. Note that the time hierarchy theorem relativizes. I made a few changes to your post, feel free to roll back my edits or edit them.

Comment: @Kaveh: the question looks much better now. Thanks!